# Ubuntu 12.10 Keeps rebooting randomly

Tags: 12.10, wubi, asus, reboot

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 using the 'Installing Ubuntu with the Windows installer' (wubi) feature on the www.ubuntu.com to install it on my computer. My computer is a ASUS with 6 ggs for ram and duo pentium core i5 64 bit system.  Ubuntu keep turning off then restarting.. and i dont know why.  It keeps doing a hard restart.

Comment: how often does this happen?

Comment: Please post the Asus model, gpu, wireless etc. (all relevant system specs). Also backup any personal data on the Wubi install as it won't last if it keeps hard rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I am having.

I have the Asus U56E laptop with 6 gigs of memory, 750 gig hard drive and i5 processor (64-bit).

Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian, Crunchbang doesn't make a difference. It will randomly reboot.

NOTE:  PCLinuxOS runs fine and I never experience this problem.  It will stay up for days, weeks, and will not reboot unless I tell it to.

If I put Ubuntu back on it, it might stay up 15 minutes, then it will randomly reboot.  I have noticed that if I go away and come back later, the screensaver will have been activated (the screen is black) and after I move the mouse the screen comes to life and then almost immediately the laptop will reboot.

If the laptop is on battery power, the laptop won't reboot it will just stay off.

I will give anyone $50 bucks to solve this problem. I am 99% sure it is something in the distro(s) because, like I said, PCLinuxOS KDE/LXDE will run for days.

$50 bucks!